# Jumbotron not behaving properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web design and right now I am using bootstrap (following a tutorial) , everything is great but the jumbotron is not behaving as it should , it's not aligning elements to the center even with container class ..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Getting Started With Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="frame_aad_aksi.png">
      <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1> 
      <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing
      responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're going to have to post the css you're using to style you're elements, if you're using any at all. Then we can start helping you.

Comment: Thanks Luminous for the reply , I don't use any CSS of my own , just the CSS that came with bootstrap

Comment: Well, is there a class called jumbotron and container in the css you're using? What browser are you using? You can view what styles are being applied in developer mode on your browser.

Comment: Yes there is , and it's working great except for aligning the image to the center . I was trying to know if there is a way to do this with the default bootstrap CSS but it seems there isn't

Answer (score 0):

like this o you mean another thing?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Getting Started With Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="frame_aad_aksi.png">
                <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>
                <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for that .. I actually figured that out yesterday , that The default behavior of text inside jumbotron is not to be centered and I had to add text-center for it to work but I was wondering if there is something simmilar to align the image to the center of the jumbotron as well using bootstrap's default CSS or should I modify the CSS

Comment: for your images you can use the class center-block like this
` <img src="img/yourimagepath.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">`